# SQL: How can i find the max value after a count?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max

Hy!

I have to determine in which month were the most exams.
My table looks: Exams(Exam_id, Student_id, Teacher_id, Subject_id, Course_id, Exam_date, Result_is).

First of all, I have to count the number of exams for each month. I did this with the following code:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4, 7) as When, COUNT(SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4,7)) as Count
FROM Exams
GROUP BY SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4, 7)
```

After this I tried to extract the max value with the following code:

```
SELECT s.When, MAX(s.Count)
FROM(
    SELECT SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4, 7) as When, COUNT(SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4,7)) as Count
    FROM Exams
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(Exam_date, 4, 7)
)s
GROUP BY s.When
```

But the results are the same, so the second part don't works. 
Where is the mistake?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you get when you remove `GROUP BY s.When` on the outer SELECT?

Comment: This error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, assuming that exam_date is of DATE type, you can get the month with `TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM')` rather than with SUBSTR.

Regarding your second part, you should compare the result to itself:

```
WITH table1 AS 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM') as when, COUNT(TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM')) as count
FROM Exams
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM'))
SELECT table1.when FROM table1 WHERE table1.count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM table1);
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I have a question. I tried to modify your code to the following: `SELECT S.when
FROM(
SELECT TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM') as when, COUNT(TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM')) as count
FROM Exams
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(exam_date, 'MM')
) S
WHERE S.count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM S)`
` Why i got error in the last line( WHERE....),  "table or view does not exist". I want only to understand well how does it works. Thank you.

Comment: Because the view doesn't really exist outside your query. When using subquery factoring, it's available for the whole query. Please read about subquery factoring.